# When a matrix has same eigenvalues of its column-swapped version?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, diagonalization, spectral-graph-theory

> What are the properties needed for a matrix $A$ to have $\mbox{Spec}(A)= \mbox{Spec}(A \cdot P)$, where
>
> \begin{equation}
> P = \begin{pmatrix} 
>   0 &  \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
>   \vdots & \cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}} & 1 & 0  \\
>   0 & \cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}} & \cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}} & \vdots \\
>   1 & 0 & \cdots & 0
>  \end{pmatrix}
> \end{equation}
>
> is the matrix that, in the product $A \cdot P$, swaps all the columns of $A$?
>
> $\mbox{Spec}(A)$ denotes the spectrum of $A$.

I've found a class of matrices (a subset of symmetric matrices of size $2^k\times 2^k$ with $k$ even) that satisfy this condition, but i was not able to figure out what are the key properties needed for $A$ to make this happen.

An example of matrix I've found is:

\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0\\
0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0\\
1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0\\
0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0\\
1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
1 &0 &0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &1 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: I love the $\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}$ on the diagonals.

Comment: I believe any matrix composed of binary values has this property.  For other number bases, special cases exist but no rules are immediately evident.

Comment: As a counterexample take the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the natural $n$-dimensional representation of the symmetric group $S_n$, namely
$$
  \sigma \in S_n\mapsto T_\sigma \in M_n(\mathbb C),
  $$
where $T_\sigma $ is the operator defined on the canonical basis by $T_\sigma (e_i)=e_{\sigma (i)}$, observe that the given matrix $P$
coincides with $T_\sigma $, where $\sigma $ is the permutation
$$
  \sigma =(n, n-1, \ldots , 2, 1).
  \tag{1}
  $$

In what follows we will restrict our discussion to values of $n$ for which $\sigma $ is an even permutation, noting that this happens if and
only if $n$ is of the form $4k$ or $4k+1$.

In 1899 G. A. Miller  [1] proved that,  for $n\geq 5$,  any element $\sigma $ of the alternating group $A_n$ is a commutator, that is,
$$
  \sigma =\tau ^{-1}\rho ^{-1}\tau \rho ,
  \tag{2}
  $$
for some $\tau $ and $\rho $ in $A_n$.

We will therefore assume  that $n\geq 5$ (in addition to the above assumption), so this  includes the case $n=2^k$ with
$k$ even of
interest to the OP,  at least for $k≥4$, and hence also the case of the big $16×16$ matrix mentioned in the statement of
the question.

Employing Miller's Theorem,
let $\tau $ and $\rho $ be as in (2) w.r.t. the permutation $\sigma $
described in (1), and put
$$
  A=T_\tau , \quad \text{and}\quad U=T_\rho .
  $$
From (2) we therefore deduce that $P=A^{-1}U^{-1}AU$, which implies that
$$
  U^{-1}AU =AP.
  \tag{3}
  $$
We then see that $A$ and $AP$ are similar matrices, so  they have the same spectrum!

To get further examples, let $B$ be
any  matrix commuting with $U$, and observe that (3) implies that
$$
  BAP=  BU^{-1}AU = U^{-1}BAU,
  $$
whence the same reasoning applies giving
$$
  \text{Spec}(BA)=\text{Spec}(BAP).
  $$

I haven't checked but I suspect that the $16\times 16$ example described in the question is of the above form.  Moreover the OP claims
to have found a whole class of matrices satisfying this condition so it would be interesting to check what is the
relationship between their examples and the ones we give here!

[1] *Miller, G. A.*, [**On the commutators of a given group.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1899-00683-9), American M. S. Bull. (2) 6, 105-109 (1899). [ZBL30.0136.03](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:30.0136.03).